# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str while insertin json to postgresql using python

Tags: python, json, postgresql, insert

**python code:**
it is the python program that i written in python i think i missed something please help me

```
import requests
import json
import psycopg2
import urllib
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen 

con = psycopg2.connect(database='test', user='postgres', password='affan@123', host='localhost', port='5432')
cursor = con.cursor()
url = 'https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datatables/ZILLOW/DATA?indicator_id=ZSFH&region_id=99999&api_key=NPzyobTgzRsGyNF_qxs-'
page=urllib.request.Request(url,headers={'User-Agent': 'chrome'})
response = urllib.request.urlopen(page).read()
json_obj = json.loads(response.decode('utf-8'))

cursor.execute(
"""create table if not exists east_data(
                indicator_id text, region_id text, date text, value integer);"""
)

nature = json_obj["datatable"]["data"]
for obj in nature:
    print(obj["indicator_id"])
    print(obj["region_id"])
    print(obj["date"])
    print(obj["value"])

    
   

    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO east_data (indicator_id, region_id, date, value ) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)", (obj["indicator_id"], obj["region_id"], obj["date"], obj["value"]))

con.commit()
con.close()
```

**error:**
this is the error occuring while running program please help me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\shaik\Desktop\api ex\nature.py", line 21, in <module>
    print(obj["indicator_id"])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

**json file:**

```
{"datatable": {"data": [["ZSFH", "99999", "2021-05-31", 418420.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2021-04-30", 406712.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2021-03-31", 397664.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2021-02-28", 385100.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2021-01-31", 385350.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2020-12-31", 383270.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2020-11-30", 378566.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2020-10-31", 375825.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2020-09-30", 369733.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2020-08-31", 366760.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2020-07-31", 336538.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2020-06-30", 367111.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2020-05-31", 360642.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2020-04-30", 358251.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2020-03-31", 357318.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2020-02-29", 356443.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2020-01-31", 355387.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2019-12-31", 353666.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2019-11-30", 352571.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2019-10-31", 352992.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2019-09-30", 354149.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2019-08-31", 353614.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2019-07-31", 352034.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2019-06-30", 349236.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2019-05-31", 345969.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2019-04-30", 343825.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2019-03-31", 341602.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2019-02-28", 338734.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2019-01-31", 336343.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2018-12-31", 334728.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2018-11-30", 333069.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2018-10-31", 328005.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2018-09-30", 322212.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2018-08-31", 317946.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2018-07-31", 315862.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2018-06-30", 315556.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2018-05-31", 314513.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2018-04-30", 312432.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2018-03-31", 310271.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2018-02-28", 308078.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2018-01-31", 305116.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2017-12-31", 301787.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2017-11-30", 297928.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2017-10-31", 296417.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2017-09-30", 294639.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2017-08-31", 294099.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2017-07-31", 292625.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2017-06-30", 290985.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2017-05-31", 290189.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2017-04-30", 289255.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2017-03-31", 287241.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2017-02-28", 286689.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2017-01-31", 286667.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2016-12-31", 287447.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2016-11-30", 286670.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2016-10-31", 285541.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2016-09-30", 284428.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2016-08-31", 282233.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2016-07-31", 280099.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2016-06-30", 277782.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2016-05-31", 274995.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2016-04-30", 272832.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2016-03-31", 271977.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2016-02-29", 270498.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2016-01-31", 268094.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2015-12-31", 264781.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2015-11-30", 262948.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2015-10-31", 261926.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2015-09-30", 261021.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2015-08-31", 260117.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2015-07-31", 259096.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2015-06-30", 258657.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2015-05-31", 258654.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2015-04-30", 258328.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2015-03-31", 257879.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2015-02-28", 257248.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2015-01-31", 257084.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2014-12-31", 256120.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2014-11-30", 254399.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2014-10-31", 251569.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2014-09-30", 248967.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2014-08-31", 247248.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2014-07-31", 245791.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2014-06-30", 243420.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2014-05-31", 240644.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2014-04-30", 239129.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2014-03-31", 237907.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2014-02-28", 236700.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2014-01-31", 234661.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2013-12-31", 233635.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2013-11-30", 233116.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2013-10-31", 233070.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2013-09-30", 232873.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2013-08-31", 232033.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2013-07-31", 230851.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2013-06-30", 229960.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2013-05-31", 228950.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2013-04-30", 225881.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2013-03-31", 222266.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2013-02-28", 219551.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2013-01-31", 218510.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2012-12-31", 217541.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2012-11-30", 215762.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2012-10-31", 214017.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2012-09-30", 212734.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2012-08-31", 211418.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2012-07-31", 210781.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2012-06-30", 209834.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2012-05-31", 209364.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2012-04-30", 209121.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2012-03-31", 209002.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2012-02-29", 207391.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2012-01-31", 205584.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2011-12-31", 203763.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2011-11-30", 203913.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2011-10-31", 204258.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2011-09-30", 204584.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2011-08-31", 204543.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2011-07-31", 204195.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2011-06-30", 203791.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2011-05-31", 203472.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2011-04-30", 204052.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2011-03-31", 205247.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2011-02-28", 206920.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2011-01-31", 207824.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2010-12-31", 208613.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2010-11-30", 208736.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2010-10-31", 209302.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2010-09-30", 210642.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2010-08-31", 212488.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2010-07-31", 213340.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2010-06-30", 213556.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2010-05-31", 213385.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2010-04-30", 213534.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2010-03-31", 213289.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2010-02-28", 214424.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2010-01-31", 216221.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2009-12-31", 218078.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2009-11-30", 218727.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2009-10-31", 218621.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2009-09-30", 216191.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2009-08-31", 214318.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2009-07-31", 213677.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2009-06-30", 216221.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2009-05-31", 218194.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2009-04-30", 219700.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2009-03-31", 220467.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2009-02-28", 220438.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2009-01-31", 219994.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2008-12-31", 219776.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2008-11-30", 220347.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2008-10-31", 220771.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2008-09-30", 221228.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2008-08-31", 221310.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2008-07-31", 221684.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2008-06-30", 220484.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2008-05-31", 221028.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2008-04-30", 221053.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2008-03-31", 222485.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2008-02-29", 222009.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2008-01-31", 220783.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2007-12-31", 219191.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2007-11-30", 217548.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2007-10-31", 216690.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2007-09-30", 218624.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2007-08-31", 220110.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2007-07-31", 219686.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2007-06-30", 217035.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2007-05-31", 213196.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2007-04-30", 210060.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2007-03-31", 205268.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2007-02-28", 202023.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2007-01-31", 200260.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2006-12-31", 198535.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2006-11-30", 197924.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2006-10-31", 196573.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2006-09-30", 193744.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2006-08-31", 189865.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2006-07-31", 187126.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2006-06-30", 187415.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2006-05-31", 188323.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2006-04-30", 188989.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2006-03-31", 188116.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2006-02-28", 186794.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2006-01-31", 184637.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2005-12-31", 183392.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2005-11-30", 181214.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2005-10-31", 179215.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2005-09-30", 177270.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2005-08-31", 176223.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2005-07-31", 174991.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2005-06-30", 172571.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2005-05-31", 169868.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2005-04-30", 167105.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2005-03-31", 165721.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2005-02-28", 164998.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2005-01-31", 164988.0]], "columns": [{"name": "indicator_id", "type": "text"}, {"name": "region_id", "type": "text"}, {"name": "date", "type": "Date"}, {"name": "value", "type": "double"}]}, "meta": {"next_cursor_id": null}}
```

Comment: The data consists of lists whose items you should access with the index number (position) of the item in the list.

Comment: `obj` is a list not a dictionary. Actually it is a list of lists: `[["ZSFH", "99999", "2021-05-31", 418420.0], ["ZSFH", "99999", "2021-04-30", 406712.0], ...]`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you do `obj["indicator_id"]`, what do you think that should mean? Why do you expect it to make sense? What happens if you try looking at `obj` overall? What is its *type*? Is that the kind of thing where it makes sense to do this operation? We can't see how your data is structured, but we can infer some things from the error message. It is important that you understand data types and how to do this kind of debugging.

Comment: then please give me solution it is very helpful for me.